# How to add rows to a table dynamically with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, html-table, rows

I want to generate a table in following fashion :

```
  <table>
      <tbody>
          <tr class="folder" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
              <td><div><img src="folder.png"><span>home</span></div></td>
              <td class="bytes">Folder</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="folder hover" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
              <td><div><img src="folder.png"><span>share</span></div></td>
              <td class="bytes">Folder</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>​
```

I want to add the rows from the CS code depending on the number of entries.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically?

Comment: I am simply placing a table in the aspx. When a button is clicked it fetched the data from the file server and puts the file lists in the table.

Comment: Each table row consists of a image and two texts. So I want to add <div> and span in the <td> so that i can apply css and make it look better!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "adding elements to html table" you should consider using Repeater for data display, which would give you clean html (exactly as you want).

Then on each click you would do what you need to do (code behind) and rebind the repeater.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Sebastian why not use a repeater or datalist to bind the data.  What source are you using to get your data from? If your pulling the data from a SQL table here is a pretty good article on how to get you started.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719636(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719636%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)